# Swift UI Toggle goes to infinite loop

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a toggle in swift ui whose value is tied to a variable in the viewModel.

```
Toggle("", isOn: $viewModel.isToggleOn)
```

Inside the viewModel the value is updated depending on publisher state:

```
aStatePublisher.sink { [weak self] state in
      switch state {
         case .someState:
            self?.isToggleOn = true
         case .someOtherState:
            self?.isToggleOn = false
         case .... // some other states does something else
      }
}
```

I also want to update the same state when the user manually toggles the toggle. Using something like this:

```
@Published var isToggleOn: Bool = false {
   didSet { 
        aState = .someState
   }
}
```

Since we already sinking on the same state that we update on switching the toggle. It creates an infinite loop.

Wondering if anyone has come across a situation like this? Where a toggle value depends on some kind of state but you also want to update the same state when the toggle is switched.

Answer (score 0):

Probably check if the value is the same to break the loop:

```
        guard let sself = self else { return }
        switch state {
        case .someState:
            if !sself.isToggleOn { sself.isToggleOn = true }
        case .someOtherState:
            if sself.isToggleOn { sself.isToggleOn = false }
        case .... // some other states does something else
        }
```